# Salesforce CRM Content Pack Preview... life after Adobe Flash?

Tags: content

Adobe Flash is officially end of life in 2020.

I assume Content Pack Preview (which [relies on Flash](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_docpack_create.htm&type=5)) will be reworked. Has there been any communication from SF regarding this matter?

Comment: I believe their intent is to rely on SVG files like some versions of PDF previews use in Content Version, but I do not have anything I can point you to as a reference. SVG files and HTML5/CSS3 animation capabilities are the primary reasons Flash is no longer in heavy use on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [Content Packs Retirement](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351309&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) it seems like SF wants to abandon content packs (which are already unavailable in Lightning Experience):

> **What is changing?**
>
> Following the Spring '20 release*, Content Packs will be retired and the capability to create new packs or change files in packs will be unavailable. Your existing content packs will remain, including the metadata associated with them. However, the preview function will no longer work for the files in the content pack, though it will still be downloadable.
>
> *Currently targeted for February 2020; date subject to change
>
> **Why is Salesforce making this change?**
>
> You may be wondering why we’re retiring this capability. Content Packs is enabled in part through Adobe Flash Player. Since Adobe Flash is in the process of being officially retired, we have decided to retire content packs and focus development on other solutions for content management.
>
> **What do you recommend?**
>
> We know that retiring a capability you’ve been using can be disruptive. To help guide you through this transition, here are a few alternatives to consider:
>
> If you want to send multiple files to a customer, you can create a public link for the folder to learn more review to this [release note](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_files_multi_file_deliveries.htm). You can also send multiple files by uploading a zip file and creating a public link to that. For information creating library folders, please review the [Create Folder Libraries article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_library_folders.htm&type=5).
>
> If you want your users to have the ability to create folders, you should ensure that they have the right permissions within the library. More information on how to do that can be found on this [Create and Edit Library Permissions article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_workspace_perm_add.htm&type=5). You should also make sure that those users have access to the Lightning Experience.